# explicit formula for recurrence relation $a_{n+1}=2a_n+\frac{1}{a_n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form

For $n\in\mathbb N$,
$$a_{n+1}=2a_n+\frac{1}{a_n},\quad a_1=1.
$$
Can any one give an explicit formula for all $a_n$? If such an explicit general formula doesn't exist, please explain it. I've tried to figure out the $n$-iterated function $f^{(n)}$ where $f(x)=2x+1/x$ or even $f(\tan(t))$. But in either cases, I failed.Since the recurrence isn't linear nor homogeneous,the generating function method doesn't apply here.

Comment: Welcome to math stack exchange! I could not find an answer with Wolfram, so I think there is no nice explicit formula.

Comment: Please check that the edits did not change the formula you meant to write. The lack of parentheses made the fraction difficult to interpret. You may find the following guide to math typesetting useful: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @Peter, I don't understand you. OP wrote "$a(1) = 1$".

Comment: Ok, sorry, did not notice that.

Comment: Thank you for answering. But I can hardly be convinced without a proof that there exists or not an explicit formula.

Answer (score 4):

We can transform this equation in to $$\dfrac{b_{n+1}}{2}=b_n+\dfrac1{b_n}$$ by substituting $b_n=\sqrt2a_n.$
Note that $$b_{n+1}-4=\dfrac{2}{b_n}(b_n-1)^2$$ and $$b_{n+1}+4=\dfrac{2}{b_n}(b_n+1)^2$$ Now $$\dfrac{b_{n+1}/4-1}{b_{n+1}/4+1}=\left(\dfrac{b_n-1}{b_n+1}\right)^2$$ Continuing this processes we can obtain
$$\dfrac{b_{n+1}/4-1}{b_{n+1}/4+1}=\left(\dfrac{b_n-1}{b_n+1}\right)^2=\left(\dfrac{4b_{n-1}-1}{4b_{n-1}+1}\right)^{2^2}=\left(\dfrac{4^2b_{n-2}-1}{4^2b_{n-2}+1}\right)^{2^3}=\cdots=\left(\dfrac{4^{n-1}b_{1}-1}{4^{n-1}b_{1}+1}\right)^{2^n}$$ You can obtain $b_{n+1}$ and hence $a_n$ from here.
$$b_{n+1}=4\left(\dfrac{1+\left(\dfrac{4^{n-1}b_{1}-1}{4^{n-1}b_{1}+1}\right)^{2^n}}{1-\left(\dfrac{4^{n-1}b_{1}-1}{4^{n-1}b_{1}+1}\right)^{2^n}}\right).$$ Therefore 
$$a_n=2\sqrt2\left(\dfrac{1+\left(\dfrac{4^{n-2}\sqrt2-1}{4^{n-2}\sqrt2+1}\right)^{2^{n-1}}}{1-\left(\dfrac{4^{n-2}\sqrt2-1}{4^{n-2}\sqrt2+1}\right)^{2^{n-1}}}\right).$$

Comment: Amazing! Can you tell me how it comes to you to calculate b(n+1)+4 and b(n+1)-4?

Comment: Would you please explain the validity of the second equality in the continuing the processes part?

Comment: Nice try! But unfortunately, your deduction breaks down when you write $$\dfrac{b_{n+1}/4-1}{b_{n+1}/4+1}=\left(\dfrac{4b_{n-1}-1}{4b_{n-1}+1}\right)^{2^2}$$ numerical evidence suggest that they're not equal, as I just plugged in several values of $n$ to compare them.

Comment: @Nilan I agree, $ \left(\dfrac{b_n-1}{b_n+1}\right)^2 \neq\left(\dfrac{4b_{n-1}-1}{4b_{n-1}+1}\right)^{‌​2^2}$

Comment: Let $F(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$, $S(y)=y^2$. Then $(F^{-1}\circ S\circ F)(x) = \frac{(a^2d-c^2b)x^2+2bd(a-c)x+bd(b-d)}{ac(c-a)x^2+2ac(d-b)x+(ad^2-cb^2)}$. Matching that with $x\mapsto\frac{2x^2+1}{x}$ yields $a=c\neq0$, $b=-d\neq0$, and then the contradiction that $a^2d=4a^2d$. Consequently there is no such $F$. The contradiction disappears when the iteration map is $x\mapsto\frac{x^2+1}{2x}$.

Comment: @ccorn: Thank you. If we can find a substitution that makes $$\dfrac{b_{n+1}-1}{b_{n+1}+1}=\left(\dfrac{b_{n}-1}{b_{n}+1}\right)^{‌​2}
$$ then easily we can derive a closed form. But your observation leads us that ther is no closed form. is n't  it?

Comment: Indeed, there is no invertible fractional linear $F$ such that $F(a_{n+1}) = \left(F(a_n)\right)^2$, and that carries over to the $b_n$ as well. It also applies if one introduces a scale factor immediately before or after squaring, because all such operations can be combined into one $F$.

Comment: @ccorn: Thank you. I had try to find a suitable for this problem. Now it was solved. Can you please explain that technique you used, at lease provide a link. Again thank you very much.

Comment: It is as simple as demonstrated above: Use the above Ansatz $F(x)=\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}$, then $F^{-1}(z)=\frac{dz-b}{-cz+a}$. Then calculate $F^{-1}\circ S\circ F$ by setting $z=\left(\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}\right)^2$. Then try to match that rational degree-$2$ map with the iteration map. This will ultimately lead to a contradiction. [Wikipedia article on Möbius transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation).

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite your expression to get $$a_{n+1}-{a_n}=a_n+\frac{1}{a_n}$$

The left hand is the usual difference sequence.  We are then motivated to look at the differential equation $$y'=y+\frac 1y$$  Which has the general solution $$y=\sqrt{\lambda e^{2x}-1}$$.  Of course, $e$ is the result of a continuous operation...it is clear that for your sequence $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a^n}\rightarrow 2$ so we expect that $$a_n\sim \sqrt{\lambda2^{2x}-1}$$  A little calculating shows that we do quite well with $\lambda \sim 1.29534632$  (I'm seeing a very close fit).

Comment: Q1: Is it possible to find an exact formula for an?

Comment: Q2:I don't understand your evaluation of an. Would you please explain it more clearly?

Comment: I don't believe there is a closed formula (no argument for that, there is usually not a closed formula and I certainly can't think of anything.  Of course I often miss things)  "Evaluation" is putting it too strongly.  For sequences, the difference $s_{n+1}-s_{n}$ is the discrete analog of the derivative.  Passing to the continuous case, I was able to solve the ODE (it's not difficult).  That tells me the shape the solution takes.  I then adjusted parameters until I got a fit I liked.  It's a good way to get asymptotic expressions for sequences.

Comment: The method is reasonable to the extent that the discrete difference $f(x+1)-f(x)$ is a passable approximation to the derivative.  In the case of exponentials, the discrete difference is just a multiple of the actual derivative so things don't get out of hand.

Answer (score 1):

Take the recurrence, and square:

$$
a^2_{n + 1} = 4 a^2_n + 4 + \frac{1}{a^2_n}
$$

We know that $a_n \to \infty$, so as a first approximation you have for $b_n = a^2_n$:

$$
b_{n + 1} = 4 b_n + 4
$$

For $b_0 = 1$ this one has solution:

$$
b_n = (n + 4) \cdot 4^{n - 1}
$$

So $a_n \sim 2^{n - 1} \sqrt{n}$. Replacing this in the recurrence would allow you to get tighter asymptotics.

Answer (score 0):

The recursion formula is $A_{n+1}= 2A_n+ \frac{1}{A_n}$.  Assuming for the moment that this **does** converge to "A" then, taking the limit of both sides, as n goes to infinity, we have $A= 2A+ \frac{1}{A}$ or $A+ \frac{1}{A}= 0$.

Multiplying by A, $A^2+ 1= 0$.  Since the limit, if it exists, would have to be real, there is **no limit**.

Comment: Yes, I know An has no limit since it is increasing and unbounded (A1=1).But it doesn't say anything about the existence of an explicit formula.